# python communication MODBUS TCP/IP raspberry pi and HMI - write value

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, tcp, modbus

I'm French student and i need your help in Python for my program.

I've got a program in my rapsberry in Python which acquire datas from temperature and hygrometry sensors.

I need to communicate these values to an Human Machine Interface supervisor by the MODBUS TCP/IP PROTOCOL to display and made some graphics of these values in my HMI

```
The IP adress of the raspberry : 172.16.0.2
The IP adress of the HMI : 172.16.0.10
```

I think I need to use package like `pyModbusTCP` or things like that but I don't understand how to use it.

Could you help me to understand how I made the communication between my Rpi and my HMI and for example how I could write the integer value `100` at the address index `1`?

Thanks for all!
Antoine

Answer (score 4):

MODBUS is a *single-master* protocol, meaning that there can only be one master, the rest of attached devices are slaves ( http://www.ni.com/white-paper/52134/en/ , similar to USB protocol, called *host* and *device* there ). In addition in MODBUS protocol a slave never starts a communications, slaves only answer to requests. Consequentially the machine on that your HMI runs has to be the MODBUS master /client ( this naming convention is a bit senseless )

For a quick general overview read this **https://www.reddit.com/r/PLC/comments/7bqppu/using_raspberry_pi_as_modbus_slave_and/** and http://www.simplymodbus.ca/TCP.htm

**pymodbus client / master on HMI machine**

From this master / client you can send requests to the RPi ( MODBUS slave / server ) with its sensors using the following code ( if one of the sensors stores its data in a register that is presented to the bus as `coil 1` by the pymodbus server that runs on the RPi, see below ). This is only an example there are other *data blocks* in MODBUS, namely *Coils, Discrete Inputs, Input Registers, Holding Registers* which of them you use depends on how you configure the MODBUS server on the RPi, normally Discrete Inputs and Input Registers are rarely used :

```
client = ModbusTcpClient('172.16.0.2')
client.write_coil(1, True)
result = client.read_coils(1,1)
print(result.bits[0])
client.close()
```

https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus

**pymodbus server / slave on Rpi**

For this to work on the RPi has to run software ( pymodbus server ) that enables it as MODBUS slave / server and the sensors have to write their values into specific memory locations that are presented to MODBUS as coils / registers. How this can be done is in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3Dgd0PDjnU and https://jacekhryniewicz.wixsite.com/website/raspberry-pi-with-modbus-tcp ( is a bit outdated )

In **https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/master/examples/common/asynchronous_server.py** is a working example of a MODBUS server that has to run onthe RPi ( read the comments, especially the lines following `# initialize your data store` )

The word *coils* has its origin in the past of MODBUS protocol which was developed when electromechanical relays with coils were used in automation technology

Comment: Could you suggest an example/ link where the data from the register is obtained; through RTU before making it into a tcpserver?